# Admin-on-rest: how to decrease button spacing and how to edit page without ID in url

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I started with admin-on-rest recently and I love what it brings. However, I am stuck on 2 issues and I was hoping to get some help:

**Question 1**

I created a custom theme with custom color pallette etcetera. How can I reduce the spacing around buttons? You can see it on the demo here: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/customers/121, the save button has an indent of maybe 20-30 pixels. Can I remove this and align the button with the input fields, title, etcetera?

**Question 2**

What is the best approach for creating an /#/user/details/ view for example, where users can edit their own account details, re-using the EDIT component? I have now added this resource:

```
<Resource name="user/details" edit={EditDetails} />
```

I can edit the account by going to /#/user/details/ID (replacing ID with the actual user ID). But I don't want to expose the ID. Better yet, the SPA doesn't need to know about the ID at all, because the API can understand a PUT request to /user/details/ as a request to update the **current user** details. So I don't actually need the SPA to send or need this ID. Any ideas on this?

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: Latest version (v1.4.0). Thanks for your reply btw

Comment: It would be useful if the one who downvoted also explained why he/she downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Theming.html#overriding-a-component-style

Customizing the `Toolbar` which contain the button will require a bit a of work in versions `1.*.*`. You'll have to create a custom `Toolbar` using the original as a starting point (https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/form/Toolbar.js) and use it as the `toolbar` prop for your form (https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#toolbar). This will be a lot easier in v2.

**Question 2:** this can be achieved using a [custom restClient](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload). In a nutshell, intercept calls which target the `user` resource and build the url yourself, not forgetting to handle the response.

However, for such a thing, I would advise against using the `admin-on-rest` mechanisms as it seems `users` are not really a resource but an application concept. As such you might want to handle this in a custom page with fetch by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a specific example for question 1. All the styles I add only apply to the button itself, not to the div that is placed around it..  I tried everything and most things I was able to change, however not for this one.

Comment: Hi Gildas, thanks a lot. Do you know when v2 will be released?

Comment: Not yet sorry. Several beta versions have been released though and we already used them successfully on many customer projects.